# Make Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction to work with staging slot

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-powershell

I'm trying to deploy azure webjob directly by following [Deploying a WebJob using PowerShell ARM Cmdlets](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deploying-a-WebJob-using-PowerShell-ARM-Cmdlets). It works fine. What changes do I need to make to the PowerShell script to deploy to a slot? I tried few things but getting errors.

```
PS C:\Users\Venkatesh> Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction -ResourceGroupName "Venky" -ResourceType "Microsoft.Web/sites/config" -ResourceName "WebSiteName/publishingcredentials" -Action list -ApiVersion "2016-08-01" -Force
Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction : ResourceNotFound : The Resource 'Microsoft.Web/sites/WebSiteName' under resource group 'Venky' was not found.
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction -ResourceGroupName "Venky" -Re ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction], ErrorResponseMessageException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ResourceNotFound,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.InvokAzureResourceActionCmdlet


PS C:\Users\Venkatesh> Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction -ResourceGroupName "Venky" -ResourceType "Microsoft.Web/sites/config" -ResourceName "WebSiteName/staging/publishingcredentials" -Action list -ApiVersion "2016-08-01" -Force
Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction : 
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction -ResourceGroupName "Venky" -Re ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction], ErrorResponseMessageException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NotFound,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.InvokAzureResourceActionCmdlet



PS C:\Users\Venkatesh> Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction -ResourceGroupName "Venky" -ResourceType "Microsoft.Web/sites/config" -ResourceName "WebSiteName/slots/staging/publishingcredentials" -Action list -ApiVersion "2016-08-01" -Force
Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction : 
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction -ResourceGroupName "Venky" -Re ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction], ErrorResponseMessageException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NotFound,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.InvokAzureResourceActionCmdlet
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resource type should be `Microsoft.Web/sites/slots/config`, resource name should be `<app name>/<slot name>/publishingcredentials`.

For example:

```
Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction -ResourceGroupName shuiapp -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/slots/config -ResourceName shuicli/shuislot/publishingcredentials -Action list -ApiVersion "2016-08-01" -Force
```

You could modify your script as below:

```
#Resource details :
$resourceGroupName = "";
$webAppName = "";
$slotname = ""
$Apiversion = "2015-08-01"

#Function to get Publishing credentials for the WebApp :
function Get-PublishingProfileCredentials($resourceGroupName, $webAppName, $slotname){

$resourceType = "Microsoft.Web/sites/slots/config"
$resourceName = "$webAppName/$slotname/publishingcredentials"
$publishingCredentials = Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -ResourceType $resourceType -ResourceName $resourceName -Action list -ApiVersion $Apiversion -Force
return $publishingCredentials
}

#Pulling authorization access token :
function Get-KuduApiAuthorisationHeaderValue($resourceGroupName, $webAppName, $slotnmae){

$publishingCredentials = Get-PublishingProfileCredentials $resourceGroupName $webAppName $slotname
return ("Basic {0}" -f [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f 
$publishingCredentials.Properties.PublishingUserName, $publishingCredentials.Properties.PublishingPassword))))
}

$accessToken = Get-KuduApiAuthorisationHeaderValue $resourceGroupName $webAppname $slotname
#Generating header to create and publish the Webjob :
$Header = @{
'Content-Disposition'='attachment; attachment; filename=Copy.zip'
'Authorization'=$accessToken
        }
```

Comment: For slot url should be `$apiUrl = "https://$webAppName-$slotname.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/<Webjob-type>/<Webjob-name>"`